# Why is my servlet latency high when my code has low latency?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have an springboot app that is not performing well under load, which is OK. Now I want to find the bottleneck to improve this app.
We are using Micrometer / Prometheus to gather metrics.

I am very confused because getting the metrics from the endpoint itself:

```
irate(http_server_requests_seconds_sum[1m]) / irate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1m])
```

will retrieve acceptable values (in Grafana): around 800ms in the worst case.

But checking the tomcat metric:

```
rate(tomcat_servlet_request_max_seconds[1m]) / rate(tomcat_servlet_request_max_seconds[1m])
```

yields a very different result: up to 7 seconds.

Is is possible that the `tomcat_servlet_request_max_seconds` metric considers time in which the requests was queued by Tomcat (accepted but waited time to process) while the `http_server_requests_seconds_sum` considers only processing time? If yes, how to improve this?

PS:
the `system_load_average_1m` also skyrockets to 16, which is much more than the number of CPUs available